# Set style of new SPView object

Tags: 2010, visual-studio-2012, spview

I have a SharePoint 2010 solution built in Visual Studio 2012 that creates a new list. I modify the default view to use certain fields. I want to change the style to Newsletter (ID 15). What method of SPView allows me to modify the style of the view?

Comment: this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.applystyle(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Tried it, does not change the View.